# 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I am trying this code:

```
string s = "[{status:1,fields:[{name:'n1',value:'v1'}]}]";
dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
var f = o.fields[0].name;
```

but line 3 gives this error, how come?  How do you get this data?

Comment: Try `var f = o[0].fields[0].name;`. The root object is an array with one element.

Comment: Why do you think that an _array_ has a `fields` property?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`o` is an array; you need to get the first element from it:

```
o[0].fields[0].name
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
 string s = "[{status:1,fields:[{name:'n1',value:'v1'}]}]";
 dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
 var f = o[0].fields[0].name;
```

Here o is the array object which holds elements and you need the first one